# KeyboardType - React Native

Tags: javascript, android, ios, mobile, react-native

Have you any ideas concerning a KeyboardType for research. I searched and I didn't find any information about that.

In example, in Android, replace the button "Ok" by an icon or another text. Hope there is a KeyboardType specified for research. I don't really want to custom the Keyboard, I think it's not really so easy...

It need to work on IOS and Android

Comment: use native-base refer this link 
http://nativebase.io/docs/v0.4.6/components

Comment: i think, if you work on component API android (like keyboard) with `ReactNative`, you can using native code (Android --> Java, iOS --> swift).
read [this](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/native-modules-android.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using a TextInput component, you can try the props [returnKeyType](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#returnkeytype) and [keyboardType](https://reactnative.dev/docs/textinput#keyboardtype). They both customize the keyboard layout and work on android and iOS.

Comment: Yes, I just found it. Thanks you very much, I looked at KeyboardType and didn't see the returnKeytype!